# Facebook API news feed Android

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get news feed from Graph API of Facebook by Android.
When i'm trying to parse this JSON it gets me nothing, not NULL, but nothing.

This is my code, that gets that feed. The code was taken 50/50 from stackoverflow and from Graph API documentation

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
    userProfile = (Profile) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Profile");
    stringsForList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringsForList);
    newsFeed = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newsFeed);

    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject mainObject = response.getJSONObject();
                        JSONObject feed = mainObject.getJSONObject("feed");
                        JSONArray data = feed.getJSONArray("data");
                        if(data == null) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data is null");
                        // StringBuilder stringForArray;

                        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
                       {
                           //stringForArray = null;
                           JSONObject singleNews = data.getJSONObject(i);
                           if(singleNews == null) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "news is null");



                       }
                    }catch(JSONException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

And here is the JSON file i'm trying to parse.

```
"feed": {
"data": [
  {
    "message": "Я їду на фестиваль ЗАХІД",
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared Zaxidfest's photo — with Василь Угринюк and 2 others.",
    "created_time": "2016-06-20T06:55:32+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1291027040925035"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared Zaxidfest's post.",
    "created_time": "2016-06-20T06:55:01+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1291026900925049"
  },
  {
    "message": "Я їду на фестиваль ЗАХІД",
    "story": "Demian Mysakovets shared Zaxidfest's photo — with Sophia Hoshko and 2 others.",
    "created_time": "2016-06-18T15:27:35+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1289904527703953"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared Територія твого розвитку's post.",
    "created_time": "2016-06-18T08:55:45+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1289698067724599"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared JavaRush.RU's photo.",
    "created_time": "2016-06-07T19:58:03+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1282518005109272"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared a link.",
    "created_time": "2016-03-31T15:42:38+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1234673696560370"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko updated his profile picture.",
    "created_time": "2016-03-19T09:53:02+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1220982634596143"
  },
  {
    "message": "posdravliayu.",
    "created_time": "2016-02-19T15:44:14+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1200638139963926"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared Zaxidfest's video.",
    "created_time": "2016-01-25T09:59:35+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1184872831540457"
  },
  {
    "story": "Oleg Misko shared Територія твого розвитку's photo.",
    "created_time": "2016-01-14T12:35:45+0000",
    "id": "1272345062793233_1178560875504986"
  }
]
```

Comment: How are you trying to fetch json data after getting array data?Or are you getting data null?

Comment: I'm not getting null, but I dont know how to properly fetch data from this JSON-file.
I need to take "story" and "created_time" Strings

Answer (score 0):

Drv, thanks a lot for your answer. The problem is that I can't get how to pass this array of news to my program. It just gives me nothing back.

If I do something like this

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender,name");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                            if (data.has("name")) {
                               nameText.setText(data.getString("name"));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
```

It gives me back username of account successfully. How can I pass news feed? :(